# When in voice call and mic is active my headset has severely reduced quality

Tags: skype, microphone, voip

I have a steel series Siberia headset and the sound quality is great when I'm not in any sort of VOIP call.  Once my mic is active though, even when the option to listen to the mic when I speak, the sounds quality is greatly diminished. The best way I can describe the sound is it sounds like I'm listening to the sounds on my computer through coming through a voice call ie. Skype, Curse Voice...

I have the audio option set the not reduce the background program sounds when in voice calls, did this through the communications tab in the microphone properties.

Can someone help me with this issue please,  it's extremely annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like an idiot, in the control panel I never saw this "Smart Audio" option at the bottom.  In there is had an option to have my speaker noise reduced while in a VOIP call.  Obviously disabled it and it works fine now!

Hope this helps someone in the future.